# Why the setTimeOut is not being called in this case?

Tags: javascript

I am using setTimeout function to call a function every 2 seconds , this is my code

This is my code

```
(function () {
    main();

    function main() {
        setTimeout(fetchdata, 2000);
    }
    var fetchdata = function () {
        alert("Boom!");
    };
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bh44ugv6/1/

but could you please tell me why the setTimeOut is not being called in this case ??

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bh44ugv6/2/

Comment: main() is a closure and setTimeout doesn't have access to function expression which haven't been defined yet

Comment: Why do you think `setTimeout` is not being called? When you debugged your program, did it visit that line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time when you call `main` the `fetchdata` is not set, so `setTimeout(fetchdata, 2000);` uses `undefined`

You would need to call `main()` after you set `fetchdata`:

```
(function () {

    function main() {
        setTimeout(fetchdata, 2000);
    }
    var fetchdata = function () {
        alert("Boom!");
    };

    main();
})();
```

Or use a named function instead:

```
(function () {

    main();

    function main() {
        setTimeout(fetchdata, 2000);
    }

    function fetchdata() {
        alert("Boom!");
    };

})();
```

Comment: So, in the first snippet, only variable declaration is hoisted to the top? whereas the assignation to function happens at the same place as in the code?

Comment: @SandeepNayak yes only the declaration itself is hoisted to top. You could also write the declaration after the assigment `fetchdata = function() {};   /*some other code*/  var fetchdata;`

Answer (score 1):

Because `fetchdata` in `main` is `undefined`, if you want use [Function Expressions](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)  you should define it before `main`, like this

```js
(function () {

    var fetchdata = function () {
        console.log("Boom!");
    }
     
    main();        
    
    function main() {
        setTimeout(fetchdata, 2000);
    }
    
})();
```

also you can define `fetchdata` as [Function Declaration](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

```js
(function () {
  main();

  function main() {
    setTimeout(fetchdata, 2000);
  }
  
  function fetchdata() {
    console.log("Boom!");
  };

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `fetchData` does not exist yet. If you change it to:

```
function fetchdata() {
    alert("Boom!");
};
```

it works.